# Why no code insight for Grails and Groovy on Eclipse STS?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

We are experimenting with Grails development on Eclipse STS, and one of the most annoying problems is that, unlike Java code, there does not appear to be any code insight features for Grails and Groovy classes and methods. Only after compiling and running a Grails web app do we find out that a method or field name does not exist.

Seriously, there has to be something out there for minimal code insight (hoping).

Comment: do you have installed "grails support" plugin?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "code insight".  STS Groovy and Grails support will highlight compile errors and underline methods and properties that cannot be statically inferred.  If you are not seeing this, then you probably do not have Grails integration configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that STS can in fact do this for you, it is basically what its Grails support is all about. Are you sure you have installed the right plugins? Documentation on this subject is right here: [1]: http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration

Side note: while STS does a decent job, I have been a happy user of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition and have never looked back to eclipse once i switched :)

Comment: I'm sure you're happy with it, but there's no way I'm dishing out $499 for a product most folks have come to expect for free, no matter how great it is. thx

Comment: well you do this stuff professionally right? so it's ok to pay for tools. besides i think the personal license is $200, not $499. the improvement in productivity i got from intellij makes that $200 look like a joke